# PHP sort an array 'like' an other array. How?

Tags: php

Example:

```
$a = [ 'b', 'd', 'a', 'e' ]
$b = [ 'e', 'a', 'q', 'b' ]
```

I want

```
$b = [ 'b', 'a', 'e', 'q']
```

I need to sort `$b` in a way to have each element already present in `$a` in the same order the element is in `$a`.

So `'b'`, `'a'`, and `'e'` are in `$a` so they come first and then the new `'q'` is last.

I'm asking about a function I don't know, if exists, or a technique to do it.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort at all.

Comment: He's asking about http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php.

Comment: How is b,a,e,q the same 'order' as b,d,a,e? Can you more clearly define the rules for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work as long as each array has distinct values and there are no string keys.

```
$b = array_merge(array_intersect($a, $b), array_diff($b, $a));
```

This does rely on undocumented behavior of `array_diff`.

Comment: Ok, this is a good answer. I really need to sort keys, but once I got right key order, with two loop I keep every value binded at the right keys. Thank you I'll try

Comment: Very nice find, but how can you guarantee this will always work? I think the documentation doesn't specify that sort order, and you don't want to rely on some undocumented implementation detail.

Comment: @GolezTrol Good point. Based on what I saw in the PHP source, it should work under the conditions I stated, but the documentation for the three functions I used is not completely clear. For `array_intersect` it does state that keys are preserved, and for `array_merge` it says that "Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array." But there is nothing in the `array_diff` documentation that refers to keys being preserved, or whether or not the result will be in any particular order.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a very long, cumbersome piece of code that does the same thing as *Don't Panic*'s very creative oneliner, you can use mine. ;-)

The advantage of this one, is that it doesn't rely on (mostly undocumented) implementation details of functions like `array_diff`. Also, it gives you a good opportunity to use a closure, which has no particular advantage apart from being pretty cool. The code could maybe be a bit shorter, but this step-by-step solution should at least be relatively easy to understand.

```
<?php
$a = [ 'b', 'd', 'a', 'e', 'x' ];
$b = [ 'e', 'a', 'q', 'b', 'g' ];

// Custom sorter functions like usort use a callback that compares items.
// The compare function should return < 0 if the first item should come 
// before the second, > 0 if the second item should come first, or 0
// if both items can be considered equal.
$sortFunction = function($i1, $i2) use ($a, $b)
{
  // Get the indexes of both item in array $a 
  $x1 = array_search($i1, $a);
  $x2 = array_search($i2, $a);
  // If both indexes are assigned, compare them.
  if ($x1 !== false && $x2 !== false)
    return $x1 - $x2;
  // Only the first item exists, so that one is 'smaller' (should come before the other)
  if ($x1 !== false)
    return -1;
  // Only the second item exists, so that one is 'smaller'
  if ($x2 !== false)
    return 1;
  // Neither exist. Keep the original order as they were in $b.
  return array_search($i1, $b) - array_search($i2, $b);
};

$c = $b;
usort($c, $sortFunction);
```